# jquery blueimp file upload not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using jquery blueimp file upload in my application. I've added the function to `$(function()`.

```
$( function() {
    $("#files').fileupload({
    url: "uploadhandler.php", 
    dataType: 'text',
    autoUpload: false,
    singleFileUploads: false,
    replaceFileInput: false,
    add: function (e, data) { 
      alert("inside add");
    }
}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');   
});
</script>
```

The file input field is not available when page loads. So the `fileupload` event is not getting triggered. I'm loading the file input field and other related html contents through an ajax call.

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button w3-margin-bottom  ">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Attach</span>
    <input id="files" name="files" type="file" style="cursor: pointer;">
</span>
```

How can I trigger fileupload event? Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Events on dynamic fields will not be triggered because you are registering an event before the field is available.

The solution to this is to delegate the event from a parent element that is available on page load. Such as document or body (Or any element which you are sure exists when the page is loaded).

So basically your code:

```
$("#files').fileupload(//do something)
```

Will be changed to:

```
$('body').on('fileupload', '#files', function() {
    // do something
});
```